# Reading from CSV - is it possible to replace all strings with NaN using na_values?

Tags: pandas, csv, nan

I am using the following line to load a file from CSV. It is very large and has about 1% of the elements as strings, but I don't know what the values are.

Is there a way to use `read_csv` and `na_values` or something to replace ALL strings with `np.nan`?

```
data = pd.read_csv(fileName,header=None,na_values=['*'])
```

Comment: Are you looking to replace all object columns?

Comment: no looking to replace any element that has a string

Answer (score 0):

The method below does not manipulate the data on reading the csv file but would occur after you read the file into memory

```
# sample data
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,'abc', '123'], ['asdf', 2, 222]], columns=list('ABC'))
# stack all your columns into one
s = df.stack()
# boolean indexing to find all your strings and set them to NULL
s.loc[s.apply(type) == np.str] = np.nan
# unstack your series
new_df = s.unstack()

     A    B    C
0    1  NaN  NaN
1  NaN    2  222
```